# whats the difference between tasksel and normal methods

Tags: installation, apt, aptitude, tasksel

Recently I have gone through `tasksel` command usage because of LAMP server setup. Why can't I use `apt-get` or `aptitude` there?  Why does the Ubuntu wiki page suggest to do it with tasksel only. Is there any specific reason?  Where should tasksel be used? whats going to happen if I use `aptitude` or `apt-get` instead of `tasksel` while installing the server.

Comment: Jai - if you are not happy with the answer - suggest a bounty will work - you'll need to update your question specifically with what you are looking for - giving examples etc.  For the bounty description - say what characteristics of the bounty will gain an acceptance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you must have used the command:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

You could have also used:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Remember that lamp-server is not a package but a task. Tasksel is generally used to install tasks on your system. Please read [its documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel).

Comment: tasksel is deprecated. The apt-get version should be preferred.

Comment: Where can we find authoritative documentation about it being deprecated?

Comment: 2018 here and still using tasksel

Comment: Looks like it is not deprecated. If it were then it should have a mention in its documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel

Comment: @Bastion and others that find this through google search, the page from the mentioned link was last edited at 2012-09-03, and there are [dangerous bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/150252) listed for tasksel on Ubuntu since 2008 so, even if the package is not explicitly marked as deprecated, one should be careful about using tasksel on Ubuntu because it seems that no one is really taking care of this package compatibility issues in Ubuntu. This is a Debian package and it seems to be [active on Debian](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/tasksel).

Comment: @logui Good point. That bug definitely is concerning, and still there!!