# 'tasksel install lamp-server' verses 'apt-get install lamp-server^'

Tags: apache2, mysql, lamp, tasksel

Is there a reason why 'tasksel install lamp-server' or 'apt-get install lamp-server^' is better than another when setting up a fresh lamp server (or other group install)? Are they really any different or does one simply map to the other somehow?

[The question that is marked as a duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178075/whats-the-difference-between-tasksel-and-normal-methods) is about practice related to installing a lamp server, this question is about philosophy behind the two methods of installing a task. lamp-server is simply used as an example. I know how to accomplish what I want to accomplish. What I'd like to know more about is why there are two methods and which method is preferred in which circumstance. The other comes across more broad than I intend this to be.

Comment: I've clarified how this question is different in the body of the question. Please review. Basically, this is a philosophy question. I'm not looking to be told how to do something, but why.

Comment: The dupe might be wrong but I am sure it has been asked before. "tasksel" is the old method. The method with the "^" was added to  "apt-get" and means "check tasks". ie. it is shorter option and more in line with all "apt-get" install methods (instead of 2 methods we now have 1). "tasksel" is still possible but you need to install it manually 1st. Clear enough? :)

Comment: tasksel is being deprecated so don't ever use it. That's pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks Rinzwind.