# Why Perl is included into lamp-server^?

Tags: apache2, php, mysql, lamp

I know there are [many methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178075/whats-the-difference-between-tasksel-and-normal-methods) and many questions about [LAMP installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack).

However, non have an answer for... **Why does command `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` installs some Perl libraries?** As described on [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP).

The help link says that, command installs the following packages: `apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libpq5 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 php5-common php5-mysql`.

**If I need only the Apache, MySQL and PHP, can I skip installing Perl?** Or these packages are needed for my "PHP based" LAMP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd never noticed this before but [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lamp-overview.html) counts LAMP as:

> Linux + Apache + MySQL + PHP/Perl/Python

But that's not the actual reason here. **These *are* required packages.** I thought I'd check a server of mine without LAMP (but LEMP from raw packages not tasksel) and it still had `libdbd-mysql-perl` (et al) installed.

When I asked why, I could see `mysql-server` was indirectly the cause:

```
$ aptitude why libdbd-mysql-perl
u   mysql-server     Depends mysql-server-5.5                             
C A mysql-server-5.5 Depends mysql-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
i A mysql-client-5.5 Depends libdbd-mysql-perl (>= 1.2202)
```

The `mysql` client itself is compiled down C but some of the scripts it ships are Perl:

```
$ file $(which mysql_find_rows)
/usr/bin/mysql_find_rows: Perl script, ASCII text executable

$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/mysql_find_rows
mysql-client-5.5: /usr/bin/mysql_find_rows
```