# What packages are different in Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server?

Tags: apt, kernel, repository, mono, unity3d

I have got Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 and Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 **with** GUI installed via Tasksel. Are there any different packages or kernels between both versions? An application using Mono and Unity3d Engine bugs out on the server version, but not on the Desktop one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [whats the difference between tasksel and normal methods](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178075/whats-the-difference-between-tasksel-and-normal-methods)

Comment: False. My question was not about Tasksel. It was about differences between Desktop and Server.

Comment: Did you install the GUI in Ubuntu Desktop through tasksel? BTW I'm happy that you solved your issue with the answer here :)

Comment: Yes I have. But now I tried Installing Ubuntu-Desktop manually. I'm testing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an overview [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F). The kernels are similar. Package differences largely depend on the packages you selected for installation.

You could, e.g., run `dpkg -l >list.txt` on both machines and then compare the lists using, e.g., diff: `diff list_a.txt list_b.txt`. Output of the comparison might be more useful if you first sort both lists with `sort`.

Comment: AFAIK, for all currently supported releases of Ubuntu, the kernels are **identical** rather than merely similar, since `linux-image-server` is just a transitional package that (according to `apt-cache show linux-image-server`) *"will always depend on linux-image-generic"*